# Проблемы с Celery

Tags: django, celery

Функция check_account() должна выполняться асинхронно, но питон просто игнорирует её.
Если поменять строчку

```
status = check_account.delay(login, password, request.user)
```

на

```
status = check_account(login, password, request.user)
```

тогда функция выполняется, но не на фоне, а как обычная часть кода.
Никак не могу понять, что надо сделать, чтобы задача выполнялась на фоне

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import *
from django.views.generic import DetailView, FormView
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from instabot import Bot
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from .tasks import check_account


class accounts(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
    model = InstAcc
    form_class = FormInstAcc
    template_name = 'primeApp/accounts.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['accs'] = InstAcc.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = FormInstAcc(request.POST or None)
        if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
            data = form.cleaned_data
            new_form = form.save(commit=False)
            new_form = request.user
            new_form.save()

            login = data["login_inst"]
            password = data["password_inst"]

            status = check_account.delay(login, password, request.user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.path_info)

        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.path_info)
```

**tasks.py**

```
from celery import shared_task
from instabot import Bot
from .models import *


@shared_task
def check_account(login, password, user):
    error = False
    try:
        bot = Bot()
        bot.login(username=login, password=password, is_threaded=True, force=True)
        user_info = bot.get_user_info(login)

        b = InstAcc(user=user,
                    login_inst=login,
                    password_inst=password,
                    username=user_info["username"],
                    follower_count=user_info["follower_count"],
                    following_count=user_info["following_count"],
                    img=user_info["profile_pic_url"])
        b.save()
        print('successsss')
    except:
        error = True
        print('error_add_account')
        InstAcc.objects.get(login_inst=login).delete()
        print('errrrror')
    return error
```

**celery.py**

```
import os
from celery import Celery


os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'instaPrime.settings')

app = Celery('instaPrime')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

Comment: Как вы запускаете celery-воркер?

Comment: Когда я прописываю: celery worker -A instaprime --loglevel=info,
выдается такое сообщение:
"celery" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
Как это можно исправить?